# Writing Python script tool for Data Driven Pages?

Tags: arcpy, data-driven-pages, python-script-tool, parameters

I'm very new to writing my own scripts.

What I am trying to accomplish is exporting JPEGs with a world file that follow data driven pages.  I would like to automate this process as much as possible, creating a tool for it.

The following script I was able to get to work if I am in the mxd file and create a folder previously that I add to the script (this test run I used C:\Data\test\PIC), then run it .  Here it is:

```
    import arcpy
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]
for pageNum in range(1, mxd.dataDrivenPages.pageCount + 1):
...     mxd.dataDrivenPages.currentPageID = pageNum
...     print "Exporting page {0} of {1}".format(str(mxd.dataDrivenPages.currentPageID), str(mxd.dataDrivenPages.pageCount))
...     arcpy.mapping.ExportToJPEG(mxd, r"C:\Data\test\PIC" + str(pageNum) + ".jpeg",df,df_export_width=1600,df_export_height=1200,world_file=True)
del mxd
del df
```

Now I'd like to take it a step further, creating a tool.  Something with parameters that allow me to pick the folder, the file name,, the width, height, etc.  So I did a test with an input for folder and file name.  It didn't work, all it did was open up the script in Notepad when it was complete.

What am I doing wrong?

Am I going about this in the right way at least?

The parameters I added were Folder for 0 and String for 1.  Here's the new script I tried when I made it into a tool:

```
import arcpy

mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]

in_folder = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
file_name = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)


for pageNum in range(1, mxd.dataDrivenPages.pageCount + 1):
...     mxd.dataDrivenPages.currentPageID = pageNum
...     print "Exporting page {0} of {1}".format(str(mxd.dataDrivenPages.currentPageID), str(mxd.dataDrivenPages.pageCount))
...     arcpy.mapping.ExportToJPEG(mxd, in_folder + file_name + str(pageNum) + ".jpeg",df,df_export_width=1600,df_export_height=1200,world_file=True)
del mxd
del df
```

Comment: Have you configured the tool dialog, and tried running it from there?

Comment: What errors did you get? It could be a problem with your file path. Try adding `arcpy.AddMessage(in_folder + file_name)` after the `file_name` variable, and then check the Geoprocessing Results window to see the message.

Comment: It doesn't seem to pop up any error when I run it.  When I run it, it opens a blank MS-DOS window and the script in Notepad.  I X out of the script and the dialog box says its completed, with no errors.

Comment: As far as configuring the tool, not sure how to go about doing that.  I created it in ArcCatalog, right clicked on my toolbox and clicked on add script.  Gave it a description, added the script file, added the parameters I thought were fitting, and clicked okay.  Is this the process I go through?

Answer (score 1):

You need to change

> in_folder + file_name

to

> in_folder + "\\" + file_name

In your ExportToJPEG

I got your code to work just fine after I made it into a tool.

[image]

Also remove the ... from your code, here's what worked for the tool.

```
import arcpy

mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]

in_folder = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
file_name = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)

for pageNum in range(1, mxd.dataDrivenPages.pageCount + 1):
    mxd.dataDrivenPages.currentPageID = pageNum
    arcpy.AddMessage( "Exporting page {0} of {1}".format(str(mxd.dataDrivenPages.currentPageID), str(mxd.dataDrivenPages.pageCount)))
    arcpy.mapping.ExportToJPEG(mxd, in_folder + "\\" + file_name + str(pageNum) + ".jpeg",df,df_export_width=1600,df_export_height=1200,world_file=True)
del mxd
del df
```

Comment: Awesome.  I got it working after messing around with it some more, but I'm going to try your way and see what it does.  Thanks for the response.

Comment: @vss031712 To show your appreciation I think you should Accept and Upvote the answer.

Comment: I'm not sure how to go about doing that.